# Regular expression for latex fonts in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

The following regular expression is taken from font-latex.el - line # 925 (auctex-11).

```
"\\(?:{[^}]+}\\)?"
```

I have tried to transform this expression so that it can accept the following text in Emacs.

```
1 - \begin{code}{}
2 - \begin{code}{{}}
3 - \begin{code}{Hello World}
4 - \begin{code}{\textbf{Hello World}}
```

Here code environment requires 2 arguments and is also added to verbatim local environments.

This regular expression target the argument after optional argument.

Transformed regular expression

```
"\\(?:{[^}]+{[^}]+}}\\)?"
```

With the transformed regular expression, only the following text is accepted.

```
1 - \begin{code}{\textbf{Hello World}}
```

What other changes do I need to make so that the other three formats are also accepted?

Comment: So whats the problem now?

Comment: I would recommend separate rules/regex for 3 and 4 -- a rule set up for 4, would necessarily exclude 3; and, 3 can be devised to necessarily exclude 4.  Unless, there is a specific reason for devising a whopper that includes every circumstance?  But, please don't be discouraged, I have spent hours devising a whopper that includes 23 different groups over a span of multiple lines, so if it's necessary, by all means clarify the question . . . .

Comment: @lawlist Thanks a lot. I devised 2 separate rules which covers all the 4 cases specified above.

Comment: If you have your answer then please post it and accept it. If it came from @lawlist's comment then you might want to ask lawlist to post that  comment as an answer, and then accept that answer. Leaving a question labeled unanswered when it has in fact been answered doesn't let people know that it is no longer unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @lawlist, multiple rules are required to capture different patterns. The following 2 rules capture all of the 4 cases specified in the question.

```
"\\(?:{[^}]*}\\)?"
"\\(?:{[^}]*{[^}]*}}\\)?"
```